# Car is stalling when I adjust AC

Tags: engine, stall

I have a 2006 Saturn Vue.  When I adjust the AC while idle my rpms start to surge and will stall.  It's also worth to note that sometimes if the AC is on while I crank up the car it will surge and turn off almost instantly.

What should I do to fix it?  I've seen a lot of suggestions for cleaning the throttle body but the issue when these suggestions were brought up was when people were turning on the AC and like I previously stated my issue is when I'm turning it on or off.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the check engine light on?

Comment: Check engine light is not on.